# How do i solve $\sin(8x)-\cos(6x)=\sqrt{3}(\sin(6x)+\sin(8x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sin(8x)-\cos(6x)=\sqrt{3}(\sin(6x)+\sin(8x))$$
How do i do this problem.. i dont know where to start..
i tried splitting 8 into (7-1) and 6 into (7+1)..it does not seen to work . Any ideas?

Comment: Try a couple of sum-to-product identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be$$\sin(8x)-\cos(6x)=\sqrt{3}(\sin(6x)+\cos(8x))?$$

$$\iff\sin8x-\sqrt3\cos8x=\sqrt3\sin6x+\cos6x$$

$$\iff\sin\left(8x-\dfrac\pi3\right)=\sin\left(6x+\dfrac\pi6\right)$$

Now $\sin y=\sin A\implies y=n\pi+(-1)^nA$ where $n$ is any integer